# Are there a good reasons to benchmark network transports across the internet instead of locally?

Tags: c#, networking, .net-core

I'm experimenting with online game development. There are various network transports, and I'd like to benchmark each to find the most ideal one for my game.

When you look up benchmarks online, they are almost always running both the server and client(s) in the same machine or process. To me it makes sense when you want to measure allocations and (de)serialization among other things.

But now I wonder, is there a good reason or necessity to actually benchmark through the internet (for purposes of comparing network transports)? The server on one machine, and one or many clients in other machines.

On one hand, I don't think there's a great reason to do that because all network transport libraries are still under the same conditions using the same underlying sockets (e.g. the latency introduced by the internet will affect all transports equally anyway).

On the other hand, it may be useful since the internet connection naturally causes more packet loss or fragmentation, which is dealt with in different ways by each transport and therefore some will be better than others. But then again you can simulate said things in the same machine yourself.

Anyway, I could be missing something so my question is: when benchmarking network transports, what good reasons are there to separate the server and client via the internet as opposed to doing it all in the same host?

Comment: Usually you have a server with many client connecting from report sites anywhere in the world.  So client and server are not at same location.  When client and server are at same location very often they are on the same machine.  When on same macine there is a virtual connection inside the machine and data never really is put onto an ethernet hardware layer.  So to get an actual benchmark over ethernet you would use two machines.

Comment: "_There are various network transports..._" That is true, but only TCP and UDP will traverse [NAPT](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3022) that most people need to use the public Internet: "_Sessions other than TCP, UDP and ICMP query type are simply not permitted from local nodes, serviced by a NAPT router._"